# Modules over a monoid: trouble with the definition.

Tags: abstract-algebra, definition, monoid

I'm having trouble with a definition.

We're working in the category of monoids. Take $A\in \mathfrak{Mon}$ and define a module over $A$ to be a set $M$ with an action:
$A\times M \rightarrow M$ such that the pair $(a,m)\mapsto am$. The question is: how do I interprit  $am$? A set doesn't usually come with an operation defined on it.

Sorry for the silly question, but I really can't make any sense of it. Thank you

Comment: I was going to say that it is just a writing convention to simplify writing the action, but Zev has beaten me to it. There is no pre-existing operation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The specific function $f:A\times M\to M$ **is** the action. That is, we **define** the expression $am$ to mean the element $f(a,m)\in M$.

Note also that the definition should include the requirement that $f$ is compatible with the monoid operation of $A$; i.e., you need
$$f(a_1,f(a_2,m))=f(a_1a_2,m)\qquad f(1,m)=m$$
or, written with the more concise notation,
$$a_1(a_2m)=(a_1a_2)m\qquad 1m=m$$
To give another approach, you can view an action as a function $\varphi:A\to \mathrm{End}(M)$ that is a monoid homomorphism, where $\mathrm{End}(M)$ is the monoid of all functions from the set $M$ to itself. The correspondence of this notion with the other notion of action is
$$\varphi(a)\text{ is the function from $M$ to $M$ defined by }\quad \varphi(a)(m)=f(a,m)$$

Comment: Don't you also need $1m = m$ for every $m \in M$?

Comment: @J.-E.Pin: Indeed, I forgot to include that. Fixed now.